# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: aa: , while compiling: Select Name from stud Where Address=aa

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrive data from android sqlite database but its givine exception that no such column:

---

**Sqlite Select Query is -:**

```
c=db.rawQuery("Select Name from stud Where Address="+a,null);
```

---

**Exceptions:-**

```
07-04 18:07:00.888: I/Database(648): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: aa
07-04 18:07:00.910: D/AndroidRuntime(648): Shutting down VM
07-04 18:07:00.910: W/dalvikvm(648): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.StudentInfoManagement/com.my.StudentInfoManagement.ListData}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: aa: , while compiling: Select Name from stud Where Address=aa
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: aa: , while compiling: Select Name from stud Where Address=aa
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at com.my.StudentInfoManagement.DataHelper.show(DataHelper.java:86)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at com.my.StudentInfoManagement.ListData.onCreate(ListData.java:19)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-04 18:07:00.948: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  ... 11 more
07-04 18:07:03.140: I/Process(648): Sending signal. PID: 648 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is simply because your sql query is wrong. When querying for a text, you need to add single quotes around the query string.

Your line should read :

```
c=db.rawQuery("Select Name from stud Where Address='"+a+"'",null);
```

Comment: problem is in Address ! This is built-in function in SQL, it can't be a column name!

Comment: Sorry, i think you are mistaken. Address has never been and will never be in any SQL implementation a reserved word. The most basic use case for using SQL is storing people and their addresses. It would be really foolish to make ADDRESS a reserved word.

Comment: I've just tested this and when I typed Address in SQL query it was blue, so why it was blue if it isn't reserved word ?!

Comment: I don't know what implementation of which software you use for your tests but take a look here : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html : "The list below shows all possible keywords used by any build of SQLite regardless of compile-time options"

Comment: I typed in SQL Server 2008 R2 and it was reserved word, so ""=> was problem too in this case and I think Address isn't valid name for column.

Comment: @BigChild : The link I gave you is from the official website of SqlLite. ADDRESS is not a reserved keyword. It is just not !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `string` then you have to express it in single quotes like:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT '"+WINNER+"' FROM '"+TABLE.trim()+"' WHERE 
       country1='"+c1.trim()+"' AND Country2='"+c2.trim()+"'", null);
```

If you are representing a `int` value
then you can simply use like this:  `+num+`